# Is repeating jQuery Ajax calls a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was experimenting with jquery AJAX calls when I faced a serious issue: when the network is particularly clogged, some of the calls were lost without triggering the error() callback, they simply remain active forever. I could set a timeout and try again after that time, but that dramatically reduced the responsiveness of the program.

I found out that a better solution to this problem was to make idempotent server calls and to create a tiny plugin that duplicates an ajax call several times until I get the first response, and then it aborts all the other tries.

However, even if this code really increases the reliability of my calls, I am not sure it could be considered a good practice, for two reasons: the first obvious one is because it increases by several times the server load (but some caching might help here), while the second one is that I didn't find anyone doing something similar here on StackOverflow, and that worried me. 
Am I missing something important?

Moreover, isn't TCP, before the browser itself, supposed to do all these reliability tasks in my place? How can be possible that calls are getting lost without triggering any failure mechanism?

I put here my plugin (just for reference, I'm not really here to ask you to give a look at my code, I just need to know if the practice is reasonable or if there is a better way to improve reliability):

```
$.fn.stubbornAjax = function(data, retryMSecs, callTimeoutMSecs, amountOfTries) {
    var a = typeof retryMSecs !== 'undefined' ? retryMSecs : 2;
    var b = typeof callTimeoutMSecs !== 'undefined' ? callTimeoutMSecs : 10;
    var d = typeof amountOfTries !== 'undefined' ? amountOfTries : 5;
    var c = a*d+b;

    var successcb = data.success;
    var errorcb = data.error;
    var completecb = data.complete;

    var timers = [];
    var calls = [];

    data.timeout = b;
    var active = true;
    function wipe() {
        for (var t in timers) 
            clearTimeout(timers[t]);
        for (var t in calls)
            calls[t].abort();       
    }
    data.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (active) {
            active = false;
            wipe();
            successcb(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            completecb(jqXHR, textStatus);
        }
    }
    data.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (active) {
            active = false;
            wipe();
            errorcb(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            completecb(jqXHR, textStatus);
        }
    }
    data.complete = null;

    for (var i=0;i<=d;i++) 
        timers.push(setTimeout(function() {calls.push($.ajax(data));}, i*a));

    timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
        if (active) {
            active = false;
            wipe();
            errorcb(null, "timeout", "timeout");
        }
    }, c));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the answer depends on the target audience and application. It could be OK to spam some (your) service with requests for some applications, but in a different context the user may be more content with an error message saying "Service is overloaded, please try later or pay for more bandwidth".

Comment: Which particular part of the network is clogged? Sending more requests usually doesn't make it better.

Comment: I am talking about the network on the client side. I am doing some asynchronous requests while the user is performing a video-conference chat, and the video-conference service uses all the bandwidth at its disposal: for this reason, sometime requests are getting lost before leaving the client network

Comment: Thanks, by the way! I was just afraid I wasn't seeing some serious issue this spamming could cause!